# Signup page redirecting to same page without printing any error

Tags: django, python-3.x

After POST method signup page always redirects to same page without printing any message
 or redirecting to homepage or login page but I am tracing it in every steps by printing something to check how it is working.
 But I can signup a new user using python shell. 
Terminal is giving me only this:
[28/Nov/2019 15:36:26] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2574
[28/Nov/2019 15:36:46] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 2574

```py
def signup(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request,'/',{})

    form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("step 2")
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit= False)
            username= form.cleaned_data['username']
            password= form.cleaned_data['password']
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            authenticate(username= username, password= password)
            Profile.objects.create(
                user=  user,
                full_name=form.cleaned_data['full_name'],
                codeforces_id= form.cleaned_data['codeforces_id'],
                Uva_Id = form.cleaned_data['Uva_Id'],
                points = 0,
                department= form.cleaned_data['department']
            )
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request,user)
                    return redirect('/') 
            return render(request, 'signup.html',{'msg':'Invalid'})
        else:
            error = form.errors
            print("error step")
            return render(request, 'signup.html',{'msg':error})


    else:
        return render(request,'signup.html',{})
```

forms.py:

```py
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget= forms.PasswordInput)
    full_name = forms.CharField(required= True)
    codeforces_id = forms.CharField(required= True)
    Uva_Id = forms.CharField(required= True)
    department = forms.CharField(required= True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields=('username','email','password','full_name','codeforces_id','Uva_Id','department')
```

signup.html:

```html
    <body>

        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="inner" style="width: 500px;">
                {% block content %}
                <form action="" method="post" style="padding-top: 40px; padding-bottom: 50px">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <h3 style="margin-bottom: 20px">New Account?</h3>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username" class="control-label">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="control-label">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password" class="control-label">password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="full_name" class="control-label">fullname</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="full_name" placeholder="Full Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="codeforces_id" class="control-label">codeforces_id</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codeforces_id" placeholder="codeforces_id">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Uva_Id" class="control-label">Uva_Id</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Uva_Id" placeholder="uva_id">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="department" class="control-label">department</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="department" placeholder="department">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" style="margin-top:20px">
                        <span>Register</span>
                    </button>
                    <p style="color: red">{{ msg }}</p>
                    <a style="float: right" href="/login">Already have an account</a>

                </form>
                {% endblock %}
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
```

Updated: 
url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
url(r'^login/$',views.Login,name= 'Login'),
url(r'^signup/$',views.signup,name='signup'),
url(r'^logout/$',views.Logout,name='logout'),
```

Comment: show me your `urls.py`  file that leads to your `signup` view

Comment: I've updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You havent included the url that the form should hit on POST

```
[...]
<form action="{% url 'name-of-the-url-that-leads-to-your-view' %}" method="post" style
[...]
```

Comment: worked.  I thought It should go to same url if I don't put any. I have done same for login and it works there.

Comment: Its working for the login if your urls for the login is your base URL, it hits /